# SearchView is still clickable after setting clickable to false in xml

Tags: android, searchview

I would like to keep my SearchView to remain unclickable until my application data has loaded from server. How can I do this? I have tried both of the following but neither have worked:

**XML:**

```
 android:clickable="false"
```

**Java:**

```
searchView.setClickable(false);
```

My xml is

```
<SearchView
        android:id="@+id/searchView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
    </SearchView>
```

Comment: can you show us some of your code where you face problem

Comment: have your tried to add  `android:focusable="false"` ?

Comment: Did you try `android:enabled="false"` ?

Comment: Both are not working. it is still clickable.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
searchView.setFocusable(false);
searchView.setClickable(false);
```

If it won't work, you can try change input type:

```
searchView.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
```